# prove isomorphisms using first isomorphism theorm

Tags: group-theory

Using first isomorphism theorem, prove the following isomorphisms

- $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\xrightarrow\sim S^1,\; $
- $\Bbb C/\Bbb R\xrightarrow\sim \Bbb R,\; $
- $\Bbb C^\times/\Bbb R^\times_+\xrightarrow\sim T,\;$
- $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb C)/\text{SL}_n(\Bbb C)\xrightarrow\sim \Bbb C^\times,\; $
- $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb Z)/\text{SL}_n(\Bbb Z)\xrightarrow\sim \{\pm1\}$

I only know the statement of first isomorphism theorem, hence solution of these questions might help to grasp its application. Thanks.

Comment: What is $T$ here ?

Comment: It is unit sphere

Comment: @R.N $T$ is not the unit sphere here. In fact, $T\cong S^1$ is the unit circle again (which you can see by computing the quotient in question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to find for each case a surjective homomorphism whose kernel is the group in the denominator.

For instance,

- For $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\xrightarrow\sim S^1$, use the exponential map $E(t)=e^{2\pi it}$.
- For $\Bbb C/\Bbb R\xrightarrow\sim \Bbb R$, use the real part $Re(z)$.
- For $\Bbb C^\times/\Bbb R^\times_+\xrightarrow\sim T$, use polar decomposition: $z= r e^{i\theta}$ or the map $z \mapsto z/|z|$.
- For the last two, use the determinant.

Comment: for 2nd shudnt it be Im(z)?

Comment: @Foggy, $Im(z)$ works as well.

Answer (score 1):

for 1th. use $f(x+iy)=y$

for 3th. use $f(A)=determinan A$.
for last one use, $f(x)=sgn x$